# How to measure LAN speed between Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, lan, ubuntu-16.04

I have Linux machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have Windows machine running Windows 10 Prof. When I open Putty terminal from Windows to Linux, I have characters appear with significant delay.

How to measure LAN speed between these two computers explicitly?

**UPDATE**

Speed is maximal number of bytes can be sent per second.

(Wow, another "secret question" found!)

Comment: What do you mean by "LAN speed" exactly?

Comment: have you used **top** to see if your CPU is being maxed by something at the time?  Can you access it directly via monitor, keyboard, and mouse? if yes is it just as slow?

Comment: @cybernard yes, I have tested top -- nothing special found; no I can't use this box via console, because it is headless. I suspect network problems.

Comment: Are they on the same LAN or is the Linux machine a remote one (if so how many "hops")?

Comment: LAN means in the same subnet

Answer (score 4):

It could be not only network issue, but if you need to check the network speed, I would suggest use iPerf utility: https://iperf.fr/
It is cross platform tool which should work fine in your scenario. You have to run iperf on one side as server and on another one as a client.

Comment: I can transfer up to `25Gb` (my interface's max) over SMB, but using `iperf3` in Windows limits me to around 13-14Gb/s. I wouldn't recommend this tool for over 10Gb in Windows.

Comment: I haven't had any unproper indication in Windows with iperf3. I suppose you measured with single thread (what may be a limit for >10GbE), that's why the results was up to 14GB/s.

Comment: It was, and the official `3.1.3` version that had the issue. After going up to `3.16` (using an unofficial build on GitHub), I had more consistent results that matched my 25Gb connection speed even with a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup samba, and try copying a multi-gig file.  Windows will tell you approx how fast the transfer is going.

Comment: This is nice for a "real world" test vs theoretical performance.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want to use the `ping` utility.

Open cmd.exe and ping the IP of the other computer to get a rough roundtrip delay.

`ping <ip or hostname>`

Comment: This does not address "How to measure LAN speed between these two computers explicitly?.. Speed is maximal number of bytes can be sent per second."